# Copy Constructor, Deep Copy, Constant Reference

Tags: c++, memory-management, constants, copy-constructor, deep-copy

Copy Constructor, Deep Copy, Constant Reference

Q. In terms of Memory Management.

**Copy constructor for a class A has the form  A(const A& a)
Why is the parameter passed by reference?
Explain why we cannot define a constructor of the form A(A a)**

Answer.
Three reasons why we do so:

1. Constant Reference when passing an object as parameter is MORE efficient
2. If we pass A(A a) without const modifier, the object that is not supposed to be changed could possibly be changed by mistake
3. We do so so that we can make Deep Copy

Those three reasons are correct?

Please let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: Um, how about this: `MyClass obj(MyClass());`

Comment: Your second reason, " `A(A a)` without the const modifier": look again. The `const` modifier wasn't the only thing you stripped from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A(A a)
```

will need to generate a copy of `a` since it is passed by value. Therefore, we need to call the copy constructor to do the copy. However, in that case, the copy constructor has not been defined, you cannot generate a copy of `a`, so it should be pass by reference.

We have format:

```
 A(const A& a)
```

Note that: constant reference is actually a reference to a constant. It means that we pass object of `A` by reference and we are not supposed to change `a` when making a copy of `a`.

The more important thing that a copy constructor takes const reference is that a temporary object can't bind to a non-const reference. Therefore, the copy constructor must take a reference to a const object to be able to make copies of temporary objects.